# Linux/RHEL Server Down with "xinetd" Alerts?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redhat, rhel6, xinetd

Suddenly one of my RHEL 6 Server `[VM]` (serving Apache on it also) went down and when i rebooted it, i saw **several** of following `/var/log/messages` as latest before it went down:

```
May  4 08:16:37 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19307 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:16:37 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19307 duration=0(sec)
May  4 08:17:08 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19363 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:17:08 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19363 duration=0(sec)
May  4 08:18:38 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19417 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:18:38 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19417 duration=0(sec)
May  4 08:18:40 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19420 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:18:42 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19420 duration=2(sec)
May  4 08:21:37 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19574 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:21:37 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19574 duration=0(sec)
May  4 08:21:38 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19577 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:21:38 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19577 duration=0(sec)
May  4 08:21:38 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19580 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:21:38 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19581 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:21:38 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19580 duration=0(sec)
May  4 08:21:38 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19581 duration=0(sec)
May  4 08:24:31 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19701 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:24:31 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19701 duration=0(sec)
May  4 08:24:49 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19713 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:24:49 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19713 duration=0(sec)
May  4 08:25:17 localhost xinetd[1928]: START: nrpe pid=19745 from=10.xx.xx.xx
May  4 08:25:17 localhost xinetd[1928]: EXIT: nrpe status=0 pid=19745 duration=0(sec)
```

- What does it mean please?

Answer (score 1):

It is connections from Nagios server with Nagios NRPE(Nagios Remote Plugin Executor) which executes checks on other hosts remotely, obviously in collaboration with xinetd. So I do not think it has anything to do with your machine been down, it is not a symptom.

Comment: But i just see that several lines only until it went down. What logs else should i check beside `/var/log/messages` please?

Comment: Well what Nagios alerted on before server went down, and can you elaborate more on how it went down, is it became inaccessible?

Comment: Server was not totally responding.. Thats why i needed to hard reset.